# Restrict direct access to s3 files from website only it should open

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to restrict direct access to files in aws s3 bucket, only from website that file should be visible, I tried with different policies. But nothing is working for me.

`{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "http referer policy example",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Allow get requests referred by www.example.com and example.com.",
      "Effect": "Allow", 
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ex-bucket/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {"aws:Referer": ["https://www.example.com/*","https://example.com/*"]}
      }
    },

    {
      "Sid": "IPAllow",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ex-bucket/*",
      "Condition": {
          "NotIpAddress": {
              "aws:SourceIp": "00.00.000.00"
          },
          "IpAddress": {
              "aws:SourceIp": "00.00.000.00"
          }
      }
    }

  ]
}`

Any suggestions on this.

Comment: check your condition. Its seem wrong `"Condition": {
          "NotIpAddress": {
              "aws:SourceIp": "54.24.189.49"
          },
          "IpAddress": {
              "aws:SourceIp": "54.24.189.49"
          }
      }`

Comment: thanks for the reply, can you tell me what's wrong in it

Comment: why you set `NotIpAddress ` and `IpAddress ` for the same IP? They are conflict with each others

Comment: @Sontya please clarify why you need this.  If you are doing it for security purposes, it is much more complicated than simply using bucket policy, and all you will achieve with this approach is a false sense of security.  If you are simply trying to prevent other sites from linking to your content without permission, then this can be achieved via policy.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - I want this for security purpose only. I want users should be able to access those files through my website only, not directly using direct link e.g. `https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/cat_image/f_bevarag‌​es.png`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to allow access to bucket with specific Domain try this

Below is an example of how to set www.example.com and example.com as valid refers.
Add the following policy in your “Add bucket policy” field:

```
{ 
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "http referer policy example",
"Statement": [ 
        { 
               "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Principal": "*", 
               "Action": "s3:GetObject",
               "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3-foo-bar/*",
               "Condition": { 
                       "StringLike": { 
                             "aws:Referer": [ 
                                    "http://www.example.com/*",
                                    "http://example.com/*" 
                              ] 
                       }
               }
        }
```

*By default accounts are restricted from accessing S3 unless they have been given access via policy. However, S3 is designed by default to allow any IP address access. So to block IP's you would have to specify denies explicitly in the policy instead of allows.*

```
{
"Id": "S3PolicyId1",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "IPDeny",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3-foo-bar/*",
        "Condition": {
            "NotIpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": "Your IP Address CIDR Notation"
            }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

If you want to disable direct access to bucket:

You can make the files private and generate **signed URLs** to allow someone temporary access to the files: [Share an Object with Others](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

Another Method can be you can [Serve Private Content via Cloudfront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html)

Or you can set a policy to restrict people from accessing the files directly which is mentioned above, only allowing them to access a file if it was linked from your website

Or you can serve those files by sending them through some script, i.e. download the file to your server and returning the file contents from there. In which case you can just make those files private in S3 or even move them to a separate bucket that is completely private. I would not recommend this method because it puts more load on your server.

Hope This helps

Comment: thanks for such a quick reply, I tried both the options. Still I can access my files directly. without going to the website

Comment: Explain what do you mean by access files directly ?

Comment: so I wrote a method to show that file on my website, where I am  showing files like logos, images and all this is good. But I want restrict direct access to my files `https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/cat_image/f_bevarages.png`

Comment: Updated the answer you need to make bucket private for ir , refer to the AWS documentation URL Shared

Comment: I have seen this, this is too many things to do. I will give a try. Thanks kush